# how to select the active day datetime bootstrap eonasdan

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I work with this excellent plugin, as I can do to make the change event work on the currently selected day , this is the code

```
$('#id_fecha').on("dp.change", function(e){alert('ok');}
```

this not work for the active day, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your implementation, the most obvious thing is there is an error in your code:

you are missing a `)` at the end:

```
 $('#id_fecha').on("dp.change", function(e){alert('ok');});
```